# What is the "pincentrum" for magnets in the molecule structure?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

So my prof explained ferromagnetism and said that permament magnets have "pincentra" so the material becomes magnetic too because the magnetic domains all point in the same direction. I don't really know how to explain it in english but what are these "pincentra" when looking at the structure of the molecule? Why do some materials have it and others don't (so they can't become permament magnets)

Comment: Is "pincentra" from a non-English language and if so what one ?  It sounds like the lecture was not in English.

Comment: Yea from Dutch, the "pincentra" I refer to were kinda explained as points in the magnet that can hold a magnetic domain, so that the domain doesn't decrease in size anymore, and that way the magnetic field stays permament?

Comment: Google Translate says this is "pin centers" in english, which sounds like "spin center" so I wonder if there's some pronounciation issue here ?

Comment: I don't think so, when I look "pincentra magnet" up in dutch, I can find articles on magnets and their domains and pincentra... Also on the English wiki on magnetic domains, I can find the term "pinned". For example this: "due to a phenomenon where the domain walls become "pinned" to defects in the crystal lattice they can be local minimums of the energy" from wiki, convenient I found this sentence because my question is, what is this phenomenon that causes the domain walls to be pinned?

Comment: Sounds like you have found your own answer.  It's perfectly acceptable on SE to answer your own question and we'd prefer questions answered than unanswered, so please write an answer if you think you have what you need.

Comment: Well the wiki page still doesn't explain what these phenomenon are that pins the domain walls, so it hasn't been answered yet.